# How can I use a node Transform Stream to turn XML into JSON

Tags: xml, json, node.js, express, proxy

How do I write a Transform Stream that turns the XML text in a node Req object into JSON so I can pipe it directly to a Node response?

I am building a sort of proxy or wrapper around an XML based web service, to turn the XML into a RESTFul JSON api. The idea is this:

User makes a request to the proxy, the proxy sends a request to the XML service, and gets back a Node Response Stream, which is transformed (by magic stream thing I can't do yet) into JSON and then piped directly back to the response and sent back to the original user.

I can get this to work quite well with Express, or a simple Node Proxy app, with the exception of the XML to JSON part. I understand that I need to build a Transform stream as defined by substack in his [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#transform) and I think I can make use of [streamify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/streamify), but I am uncertain how to proceed.

here is the route I have set up for my express 4 app. I am using superagent to make the second request.  This works, but doesn't transform.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    request = require('superagent'),

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    request
        .post('http://server.com/some.xml')
       // .pipe(converter(res))
        .pipe(res)

});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a [Transform stream](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) that internally uses a module like [sax](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) to parse the XML. From there it's up to you how you want to format/output the JSON (especially how you want to deal with XML node attributes and the like).

Also, I'm not familiar with `superagent`, but you will need to handle the case when the xml request fails so you know to `res.send(500);` instead.

Comment: Accepted as this pointed me in the right direction. However I didn't pursue it all the way, as it turned out to be in the wrong direction for my project